# Test data generation performance using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, testing, random

I need a big Table having over 10,000,000+ rows to test some thing.

I Used this query

```
DECLARE @_i INT
DECLARE @_MAX INT
SET @_i = 0
SET @_MAX = 10000000
WHILE (@_i<@_MAX)
BEGIN
--WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:00.001'
INSERT INTO [BigData].[dbo].[Log]
([Actime],[CustomerID],[ProductID],
            [Type]
           ,[URL])

SELECT GETDATE() [Actime]
      ,Round(RAND()* 20000, 0)[CustomerID]
      ,Round(RAND()* 2000, 0) [ProductID]
      ,Round(RAND()* 100, 0)[Type]
      ,CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()) [URL]
Set @_i=@_i+1
 END
```

OK, it was working, but also too slow. Is there a better query doing  the issue faster?

Comment: What does "*engender*" mean?

Comment: I was going to suggest a set-based approach, but it is not providing random values for `CustomerID, ProductId, Type`.  The `WHILE` loop construct causes an implicit transaction for each iteration of the loop.  One quick option is to use `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMMIT`.

Comment: thanks a lot for fixed my poor English :)

Comment: Hi, DMason, did you mean I must add BEGIN TRAN and COMMIT in my loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying [Jeff Moden's data generation solution](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Data+Generation/87901/) to your problem (change `@NumberOfRows` assignment to the number of rows you need):

```
DECLARE @NumberOfRows INT,
        @CustomerIDStart INT,
        @CustomerIDEnd INT,
        @CustomerIDRange INT,
        @ProductIDStart INT,
        @ProductIDEnd INT,
        @ProductIDRange INT,
        @TypeStart INT,
        @TypeEnd INT,
        @TypeRange INT;

-- define number of rows to insert, boundaries for column values
 SELECT @NumberOfRows = 5000,

        @CustomerIDStart = 1,
        @CustomerIDEnd = 20000,
        @CustomerIDRange = @CustomerIDEnd - @CustomerIDStart + 1,

        @ProductIDStart = 1,
        @ProductIDEnd = 2000,
        @ProductIDRange = @ProductIDEnd - @ProductIDStart + 1,

        @TypeStart = 1,
        @TypeEnd = 100,
        @TypeRange = @TypeEnd - @TypeStart + 1;

-- temp table conditional drop
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Log','U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Log;

-- create table and populate values
 SELECT TOP (@NumberOfRows)
    CustomerID =  ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % @CustomerIDRange + @CustomerIDStart,
    ProductID = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % @ProductIDRange + @ProductIDStart,
    Type = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % @TypeRange + @TypeStart,
    URL = CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), NEWID())
 INTO #Log
 FROM sys.all_columns ac1
 CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns ac2

 SELECT * FROM #Log;
```

Comment: I try you SQL, but always got an excetion ,「System.OutOfMemoryException」

Comment: What value did you use for the `@NumberOfRows` variable? Your SSMS client is likely the bottleneck here.

Comment: I use 5000, and I trid 1, still got the Exception

Comment: I guess it some memory cache reason , after I restart my SSMS (not SQL Server ), it worked!!
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use your loop to quickly seed 3163 rows. (really any table with SQRT(10000000) rows will do.

Then use CROSS JOIN to itself.

```
 INSERT INTO [BigData].[dbo].[Log]
 SELECT GETDATE() [Actime]
      ,Round(RAND()* 20000, 0)[CustomerID]
      ,Round(RAND()* 2000, 0) [ProductID]
      ,Round(RAND()* 100, 0)[Type]
      ,CONVERT(varchar(255), NEWID()) [URL]
      FROM [BigData].[dbo].[Log] a CROSS JOIN [BigData].[dbo].[Log] b
```